# how to use Angularjs forEach function with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have data stored in Firebase which I am trying to retrieve if couple of conditions are met, if not then load an image. I have tempted the code below but on execution the if statements are ignored and the image is always loaded.

```
`var refMyData = new Firebase("https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/meetings");

refMyData.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();

        if(childData.date == "11/5/2016") {
                $scope.meetingDate = childData.meetingDate;
                $scope.startTime = childData.startTime;
                $scope.endTime = childData.endTime;

                return true;

            } else if (childData.specialMSG == "6/8/2016") {
                $scope.specialMessage = "All meetings are canceled";            

                return true;

            } else {
                $scope.myLogoImg = 'img/logo.png';

                return true;
            };
      });
    });`
```

I have the following JSON data in Firebase, with total 30 objects.

```
`[{
    "meetingDate": 11/5/2016",
    "startTime": "12:45",
    "endTime": "14:20"
}, {
    "meetingDate": "12/5/2016",
    "startTime": "12:40",
    "endTime": "13:00"
}, {
    "meetingDate": "13/5/2016",
    "startTime": "15:45",
    "endTime": "17:00"
}]`
```

Comment: data type miss match. date value to json object and "6/8/2016" and "11/5/2016" are not same. you must convert "11/5/2016" and "6/8/2016" into date before check

Comment: I'm checking "11/5/2016" with childData.date == "11/5/2016", which are both strings. Do I still need to convert them into dates? thanks

Comment: can you please `console.log(childData.date)` and `console.log(childData.specialMSG)`. See if the right data are there

Comment: Yes, I get the right dates in the console. Wondering if there is an issue with how the if-condition works within the forEach or is a better way of doing it? Thanks